# Regex numbers + text from string php

Tags: php

I have a string with text and french zip code and french city.

```
$str="lore ipsum facto lore ipsum 75000 Paris";
```

I would like to extract : "75000 Paris"

I know how to extract the zip code :

```
preg_match('/(\d{5})/',$str, $matches);
```

But I don't know how to add also the city after.
An idea to help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: `/(\d{5}).+/` should do it, infact you don't need the brackets: \d{5}.+\

Comment: Can there be text after Paris?

Comment: What about cities with multiple "words"? What about strings that just happen to have a 5 digit number? Have these been considered?

Comment: My solution will work for multiple words in the city name assuming that the city name is definitely the last thing that occurs in the string, otherwise this becomes much more of a problem and I don't think regex can be of much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your regex to:

```
preg_match('/(\d{5} [a-zàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ\- ]+)/i',$str, $matches);
```

This way you check after the zipcode to have a space and letters (a-z or special french characters (lower case or upper case)), `-` or an empty space. I think this cover all cities.

For example for this string:

`lore 99912345 La Roche-sur-Yon` the match will be:  `12345 La Roche-sur-Yon`

`Avenue de Baixas 66240 Saint-Estève` will match: `66240 Saint-Estève`

Comment: This is a better answer than mine in the comments because it will only get the next word after the postcode and accounts for the space between the two.

Only thing that could cause you problems is if there are 5 numerical characters in the string _before_ the postcode.

Although, this will only work for city names with one word in their name.

Comment: If you have some numeric before the zipcode it will get only the last 5 and the string after that. For example for this input `lore 99975000 Paris City` will return: `75000 Paris City`

Comment: Doesn't works for "66100 Saint-Estève" its stop on Saint-Est

Comment: @Bisvan I updated my answer with special french characters. I Think I added all of them. Also I added `/i` so it will be case insensitive (accepts lower case and upper case)

Comment: $test="Avenue de Baixas 66240 Saint-Estève";
preg_match('/(\d{5} [A-Zzàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ- ]+)/i',$test, $matches);
print_r($matches);

Comment: @Bisvan Sorry i forgot to escape the `-` . I updated my answer. I only added the \ before `-`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this

`preg_match('/(\d{5}\s\S+)/',$str, $matches);`

You will find your result in $matches array.

**Note** : this will only work with city names with one word.
If you need multiple word support then may be regrex isn't the perfect thing because it may fetch unnecessary word too.

Comment: There are city names which have spaces in them. Los Angeles being one of the more famous ones, and I'm positive far from the only one.